# arpspoof on corporate network

Tags: arp-spoofing

I've just been learning some things about arp poisoning and would be tempted to use it on colleagues to inject some javascript alerts into their pages when they aren't working to freak them out - but was wondering if my virtual machine / arp spoof packets could be picked up / linked back to my host machine by site security?

Comment: Yes, the traffic could be traced. No we aren't going to give you advice on how to hack your co-workers or circumvent your company security.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can. Of course it depends on conditions like:

- How are the ethernet switches configured
- Is there any logging enabled

Also on non-technical conditions like what happens after they freak out:

- You don't say a thing they report it to IT and an investigation starts (and they might look at everyone's browsing history, looking for "arp spoofing")
- You tell them it was a prank and they report it to HR

In the end the main question you should ask yourself is: **would this violate company policies, and if so is it a firing offense?** followed shortly by *is it worth*?

How about setting up a private network on your home computer and playing in a safe environment.